# How to use lookup field as a condition check to perform an action in sharepoint designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, workflow, designer-workflow, spfieldlookupvalue

I have a list named as "Class" and title column with fields (SMS, BP, HVL, TA).

The second list "DataCollection" has a column from Class using lookup.

Now, I want to check the condition in designer workflow 
"if current item: Class equals SMS"
    Action >> Send Email to XXX@domain.com
    End workflow

The system shows error when I 
I execute this workflow.

Somebody please help to find a solution.

Comment: Have you added your workflow on second list, DataCollection list?

Comment: yes, added to the second list "DataCollection"

Comment: This is SharePoint designer workflow 2013, right? Also, Can you post the error you are getting after executing the workflow?

Comment: The workflow is executing smoothly but this condition is not applying due to lookup field value check. I mean, the workflow didn't check this if condition

Comment: i couldn't see any option to attach the screenshots

Comment: You can get the Image option to attach screenshot while editing your existing question. Or you can add an error text you are getting after workflow fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow Below Steps:

1. At the Starting of your workflow, use **Set Workflow Variable** action and create on new variable of type string. Set it's value as a lookup column value. (See attached image below).
2. Add **IF condition**, In Left side,  Select the workflow variable we created.
3. In Right side of **`equals`**, Type **SMS**.
4. Inside IF condition, Use **Send Email** action.

[image]

**Note**: If your lookup column is set to allow multiple values then instead of **`equals`** operator, you can use **`contains`** operator.

Comment: Many thanks Brother. it worked well..........!!!

Comment: Welcome. Please Upvote ( ^ ) and accept it is an answer if it helped you.